# Clipboard erased when quitting Blender on Ubuntu

Tags: linux

If you highlight text in Blender and press <kbd>CTL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy it, then quit Blender, you can no longer paste that text.

Why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I posted a [bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T38674) on this, but apparently it's not Blender's fault.

As Sergey explained in the bug report, Blender only instructs the [clipboard manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipboard_manager) to save the text, but in Ubuntu, this is a bug that affects many programs.  You can read more about why it happens [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ClipboardPersistence).

Going to the Ubuntu Software Center and installing the application `Parcellite`, which is an alternative clipboard manager has fixed the problem for me.

EDIT: I also had some problems with `Parcellite` and Blender working together.  You could try a different clipboard manager.

Comment: This is a long-standing design flaw in the X clipboard. The master Ubuntu bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/11334